# How to use this sql add lock in the rows?

Tags: mysql, locking

SQL:

```
 INSERT LOW_PRIORITY IGNORE INTO A_new (??) SELECT ?? FROM A FORCE INDEX(`PRIMARY`) 
 WHERE ((`id` >='XX' )) AND ((`id` <= 'XX')) LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

Is it possible to add S Locks in the range rows without any transaction?

If not,does this sql only work in transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer from mysql document.

> INSERT INTO T SELECT ... FROM S WHERE ... sets an exclusive index
>   record lock (without a gap lock) on each row inserted into T. If the
>   transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED, InnoDB does the search
>   on S as a consistent read (no locks). Otherwise, InnoDB sets shared
>   next-key locks on rows from S. InnoDB has to set locks in the latter
>   case: During roll-forward recovery using a statement-based binary log,
>   every SQL statement must be executed in exactly the same way it was
>   done originally.